# Laravel 8 Unique form validation ignore

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

My form edit

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.akun.update', $akun->id_pegawai) }}" method="POST">
@csrf
@method('patch')
<input type="text" class="form-control" @if (old('nip')) value="{{old('nip')}}" @else value="{{$akun->nip}}" @endif name="nip">
```

My Route

```
Route::patch('admin/akun/{id_pegawai}', 'AkunController@update')->name('admin.akun.update');
```

My Controller

```
public function update(Request $req, $id_pegawai)
{
    $user = new User;
    $pegawai = new Pegawai;
    $this->validate($req, [
        'nip' => ["required", "unique:users,nip," . $id_pegawai],
    ]);
}
```

condition: I edit my data, I have a unique field, if I don't change the unique field it will be successfully edited, and if I replace it with the same data there will be an alert

Comment: How do you retrieve `$id_pegawai` ?

Comment: can you verify that `$id_pegawai` is having the correct value to ignore? Also to what column `$id_pegawai` correlates on database?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier i want update my data. but i have unique field. I've thrown id_pegawai on the form

Comment: Ok but you don't give us any information that we can use to help you. We need to know more information about your variable. How do you retrieve it (you have somewhere `$id_pegawai = ...` I presume) to what this value is supposed to correspond to. And also, what's the content of `$id_pegawai`

Comment: ok, thankyou, i edit my question. and make it clearer

Comment: You can edit your question and add additional information instead

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I've added an additional explanation

Comment: The thing is; you're validating the `nip`of the `users` table against the `id` of your `pegawais` table but `->ignore($id)` expect the `id` of the `user` (or `null` if it doesn't exist yet), not `pegawai`. But I'm not sure about how you should do it since you're creating both in the update, which confuse me.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier I want validation from column id_pegawai not id. How to?

Comment: As @ClémentBaconnier give an answer, your code will be like `'nip' => ["required", Rule::unique('pegawais', 'nip')->ignore($id_pegawai, 'id_pegawai')],`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify against which column you want to be unique

```
 Rule::unique('users', 'nip')->ignore($id_pegawai, 'id_pegawai'),
```

Comment: Definitely this is the issue. Cause by default it ignore the `id` column. So OP just need to specify the column name to be ingored

Comment: No problem! But don't forget to accept the answer so it close the question.

Comment: What if `$id_pegawai` is a user input (because user want to input manually the id)? The docs has warn and I think against it idk other way around :( https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique. `You should never pass any user controlled request input into the ignore method. Instead, you should only pass a system generated unique ID such as an auto-incrementing ID or UUID from an Eloquent model instance. Otherwise, your application will be vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.`

Comment: @Fahmi in my opinon, letting your users defining they own ID on which your application have to relies to, is never a good idea. I would still have my own "app" IDs and the user ID. However, if this cannot be applied, I would make a [custom Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-rule-objects) and does the check in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
["required", "unique:users,nip,".$id_pegawai]
```

Documentatin: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique

Syntax: unique:table,column,except,idColumn