# Laravel 8: Rule::unique ignore doesn't work?

Tags: laravel

Duplicates:
[Laravel 8 Unique form validation ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64512801/laravel-8-unique-form-validation-ignore)

following this [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique)

This is my request validation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'LFNumber'  => ['required', 'integer', Rule::unique('lost_and_found', 'id')->ignore($this->id, 'id')],
    ];
}
```

I'm trying to `edit` some fields of the form but I either get `LFNumber already exist` or  `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'LFNumber'`

I tried `Rule::unique('lost_and_found', 'LFNumber')->ignore($this->id, 'id')` to select the `LFNumber` column and ignore the id. But still he same errors.

Comment: Please provide more codes. Full code of controller and model.

Comment: This means the validation passes but the SQL query fails. It's likely you are doing an insert instead of an update

Comment: @apokryfos Weird, the route of the update is ```Route::put``` Even in the edit form it's ```@method('put')```

Answer (score 1):

If the unique column is `LFNumber` then you don't need to provide it:

```php
'LFNumber'  => ['required', 'integer', Rule::unique('lost_and_found')->ignore($this->id)],
```

This will check `lost_and_found.LFNumber` column while ignoring row with Primary Key matching `$this->id` (assuming this value is really the id on that column)

Comment: Nice, but now I have error ```The l f number has already been taken.```

Comment: Meaning validation fails not the DB, if I understand correctly? What's the `$this->id` value in your case and are you sure there is no conflict with another row in the db?

Comment: the value of the id is ```139```  and ```LFNumber``` is ```1```. Yes I'm sure there aren't any conflicts of rows

Comment: I mean is the value of `$this->id` the id/primary key of the row/model you are updating?